# Migration syntax error after custom Doctrine Type in Symfony 4

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

When I try to make custom Doctrine Type like in code below:

config/packages/doctrine.yaml

```
parameters:
    # Adds a fallback DATABASE_URL if the env var is not set.
    # This allows you to run cache:warmup even if your
    # environment variables are not available yet.
    # You should not need to change this value.
    env(DATABASE_URL): ''

doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: '5.7'
        charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8mb4
            collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
        types:
            pickupPointDetails: App\Utils\Types\PickupPointDetailsType
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

PickupPointDetailsType:

```
<?php

namespace App\Utils\Types;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;
use App\Utils\Order\PickupPointDetails;

/**
 * Class PickupPointDetailsType
 */
class PickupPointDetailsType extends Type
{
    const PICKUP_POINT_DETAILS = 'pickupPointDetails';

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return self::PICKUP_POINT_DETAILS;
    }

    /**
     * @param array            $fieldDeclaration
     * @param AbstractPlatform $platform
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return 'PICKUP_POINT_DETAILS';
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed            $value
     * @param AbstractPlatform $platform
     *
     * @return PickupPointDetails
     */
    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform): PickupPointDetails
    {
        list($name, $city, $informations) = sscanf($value, 'PICKUP_POINT_DETAILS(%s, %s, %s)');

        return new PickupPointDetails($name, $city, $informations);
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed            $value
     * @param AbstractPlatform $platform
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        $value = sprintf('PICKUP_POINT_DETAILS(%s, %s, %s)', $value->getName(), $value->getCity(), $value->getInformations());

        return $value;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function canRequireSQLConversion()
    {
        return true;
    }

//    /**
//     * {@inheritdoc}
//     */
//    public function requiresSQLCommentHint(AbstractPlatform $platform)
//    {
//        return true;
//    }
//
//    /**
//     * @param string           $sqlExpr
//     * @param AbstractPlatform $platform
//     *
//     * @return string
//     */
//    public function convertToPHPValueSQL($sqlExpr, $platform)
//    {
//        return sprintf('AsText(%s)', $sqlExpr);
//    }
//
//    /**
//     * @param string           $sqlExpr
//     * @param AbstractPlatform $platform
//     *
//     * @return string
//     */
//    public function convertToDatabaseValueSQL($sqlExpr, AbstractPlatform $platform)
//    {
//        return sprintf('PointFromText(%s)', $sqlExpr);
//    }
}
```

In next step I generate migrations by DoctrineMigrationsBundle and this is generated code:

```
/**
 * Auto-generated Migration: Please modify to your needs!
 */
final class Version20190329095621 extends AbstractMigration
{
    public function getDescription() : string
    {
        return '';
    }

    public function up(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() !== 'mysql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'mysql\'.');

        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE orders ADD pickup_point_details PICKUP_POINT_DETAILS NOT NULL COMMENT \'(DC2Type:pickupPointDetails)\', ADD pickup_point_back_details PICKUP_POINT_DETAILS NOT NULL COMMENT \'(DC2Type:pickupPointDetails)\', DROP pickup_point_data, DROP pickup_point_back_data');
    }

    public function down(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        // this down() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() !== 'mysql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'mysql\'.');

        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE orders ADD pickup_point_data VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci, ADD pickup_point_back_data VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci, DROP pickup_point_details, DROP pickup_point_back_details');
    }
}
```

And after execute migration I have syntax error in console:

```
Migrating up to 20190329095621 from 20190329094245

  ++ migrating 20190329095621

     -> ALTER TABLE orders ADD pickup_point_details PICKUP_POINT_DETAILS NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:pickupPointDetails)', ADD pickup_point_back_details PICKUP_POINT_DETAILS NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:pickupPointDetails)', DROP pickup_point_data, DROP pickup_point_back_data
Migration 20190329095621 failed during Execution. Error An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE orders ADD pickup_point_details PICKUP_POINT_DETAILS NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:pickupPointDetails)', ADD pickup_point_back_details PICKUP_POINT_DETAILS NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:pickupPointDetails)', DROP pickup_point_data, DROP pickup_point_back_data':

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PICKUP_POINT_DETAILS NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:pickupPointDetails)', ADD pickup' at line 1

In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 79:

  An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE orders ADD pickup_point_details PICKUP_POINT_DETAILS NOT NULL C
  OMMENT '(DC2Type:pickupPointDetails)', ADD pickup_point_back_details PICKUP_POINT_DETAILS NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Ty
  pe:pickupPointDetails)', DROP pickup_point_data, DROP pickup_point_back_data':

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual tha
  t corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PICKUP_POINT_DETAILS NOT NULL COMMENT
   '(DC2Type:pickupPointDetails)', ADD pickup' at line 1


In PDOConnection.php line 90:

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual tha
  t corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PICKUP_POINT_DETAILS NOT NULL COMMENT
   '(DC2Type:pickupPointDetails)', ADD pickup' at line 1


In PDOConnection.php line 88:

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual tha
  t corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PICKUP_POINT_DETAILS NOT NULL COMMENT
   '(DC2Type:pickupPointDetails)', ADD pickup' at line 1
```

Anyone have idea what I made wrong?

Symfony 4

Comment: your `getSQLDeclaration` is wrong, it should return an sql column definition (plus stuff), you're returning something .... weird, like capitalized field name. it should be "VARCHAR(100)" or "INT" or whatever.

Comment: @Jakumi I made my code with this tutorial https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#custom-mapping-types. I fix my code with your informations and it works! thanks

Comment: the tutorial has an important line before that `CREATE DOMAIN MyMoney AS DECIMAL(18,3);` which makes "MyMoney" into an actual type. So it works in the tutorial then ... however, that's postgresql-specific